# Парадокс худший и средний случай алгоритм обменной сортировки

Tags: c++

Не могу понять почему при худшем случае, когда количество обменов и сравнений больше функция работает быстрее, чем в среднем случае? Вот код самого алгоритма. Худший случай отсортированный в обратную сторону массив, а средний это произвольный набор.
Для массивов с 100000 элементами результаты были для среднего 40 сек,а для худшего 35 сек.

```
template< class T >
void bubbleSort(T* arr, int size)

{
    T tmp;

for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) // i - номер прохода
{            
    for(int j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) // внутренний цикл прохода
    {     
        if (arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) 
        {
            tmp = arr[j + 1]; 
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]; 
            arr[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: предсказатель переходов. Короткий ответ. И да, здесь нету худшего и лучшего случая. Здесь всегда (N-1)^2 операций.

Comment: Но я все же не понял почему он считает медленнее на целых 5 секунд если действий меньше?

Comment: это не подходит(

Comment: @AtaiNnno именно это и подходит.

Comment: @AtaiNnno обращение к памяти, по сравнению с обращением к кэшу процессора - очень дорогая операция, поэтому промахи предсказателя так сказываются на скорости.

Comment: @AtaiNnno Почему не подходит? Как раз Ваш случай, судя по всему.

Comment: Я до сих пор не понимаю( есть ли книга какая нибудь на эту тему. Англ язык не знаю.

Comment: Эффект наличествует: https://ideone.com/KHUS7T Скорее всего связан с локальностью данных в кэше - поскольку в худшем случае постоянно идет своп соседних данных, явно остающихся не то что в кэше, а едва ли не прямо в регистрах процессора :)

Comment: Grundy же отлично расписал, что происходит и откуда замедление

Comment: @AtaiNnno не переживайте так, конвейерные процессоры много алгоритмов поставили с ног на уши, все нормально, просто нужно помнить, что у процессора есть собственная память, пока он работает с ней, все быстро, как только начал перечитывать из ОЗУ, скорость падает. Толковые материалы видел только на английском...

Comment: Спасибо большое